# Calculation of elements of $S_6$ in cycle notation, (indice types)

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

Suppose I wanted to enact the calculation of elements of S6 in cycle notation of:

$((1234)(56))^{10}$ where the numbers in both brackets are raised to the power $10.$

My teacher has the answer as $(13)(24)$ but he has not explained this, I assume that I would have from $((1234)(56))^{10}= (1234)^{10}(56)^{10}$   (since the brackets commute).

And then if I break the indice down to let $(1234)^{10} = ((1234)^2)^5$ I get $((13)(24))^5$. Do we ignore the $(56)$ here?

Please explain this, my exam is in two days. And my understanding is really lacking for questions such as these.

Comment: Does it help if you first verify that $(1234)^4$ and $(56)^2$ are both the identity? Recall that the usual iterated power rule holds in any group $G$: if $a\in G$ and $m,n\in\Bbb{Z}$ then $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$. As does the rule $a^{m+n}=a^m\cdot a^n$. You seem to be aware that $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ only when $ab=ba$, $a,b\in G$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you sir for your quick response. Yes sir, I do understand that - but I don't see why the answer is not (13)(24)(56). Since by considering (56)^2 =(56).

Comment: $(56)^2=(56)(56)=(5)(6)$ is the identity surely? The $n$th power of an $n$-cycle is always the identity. That applies in the case $n=2$ as well.

Comment: Thank you, I rushed that which is why I made the error - really appreciate your help :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you got this sorted out. When you find the time,  you can also post it as an answer.